# Extra fields Django-registration Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Good evening, I am using django-registration for a Web application; By using this, the form that has default django-registration only has 4 fields (username, email, password, repeat password). How to add more fields to this form and store them in the database correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used django-registrations but I found a link which might be helpful to you.

All you need to do is extend the class 'RegistrationForm' and add more fields.

Something like this:
**forms.py**

```
import from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
   extra_field = forms.EmailField()
   extra_field_2 ...
```

Then, handle the form POST and save these details.

http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/forms.html